# Grey separator line on top of uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm struggling with this for the last few hours and I cannot find a fix for it...
In a UITableView I insert a list of custom UITableViewCells with all a different color. These colors are part of a UIView which acts as the backgroundView of the tableviewCell When I initialize the UITableView, I set

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

However, on each cell at the top there is still a thin gray line. This line is not from the textLabel (this label has a smaller frame then the actual cell) and neither from the UIView which contains the color (the layer.borderwidth = 0.0f and the color is clearColor).

[image: Tableview with cells]

**EDIT**

Okay, I found out that the lines do come from the UIView which contain the background color. However disabling them, leads to transparant cells when I reorder them, this is a result of the drawRect in this UIView with the folowing code to draw the UIView:

```
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), true);
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.bounds);
```

Anyone knows a way to fix this?

**SOLVED**

Pretty stupid by me, but the cells didn't have a backgroundView... So by adding these two lines in the custom cell class the problem was solved!

```
self.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot of it?

Comment: Are you using Xcode 6/iOS 8?

Comment: Could be tables superview background colour, the cells background view colour or the content view colour showing through?

Comment: Nope using ios 7 with XCode 5

Comment: Changing the background of the tableview or superview doesn't change it. When I reorder the cells in editing mode, I can see that the border/line is attached to the cell.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer for clarity, and click the checkmark next to it to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution to my question. By setting a UIView in the backgroundView of the cell class, and filling it with a white background color, this fixed the problem.

`self.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`
`self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

Comment: Clips To Bounds Cell also fix this issue